# Simple SELECT query fails

Tags: sql-server-2005

Consider the fowling structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [tblEntityLogs]
(
    [EntityLogId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityCountCurrent] [float] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

When executing the query underneath I get an empty row returned...

```
DECLARE @N FLOAT
SET @N = 666

SELECT ISNULL(tblEntityLogs.EntityCountCurrent, @N) AS EntityCountCurrent
FROM tblEntityLogs
```

And if I do:

```
SELECT tblEntityLogs.EntityCountCurrent FROM tblEntityLogs
```

The same thing happens. I don't even get `NULL` back.

**Note: The table is empty.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the table is empty then you won't get anything back - it's by design.

Although, I don't why you'd use/test it with IsNull as your table structure doesn't allow Nulls.

Comment: Strange. And yeah; you're right. In the midst of my frustration I threw a random `ISNULL()` in there :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's not failing, it's returning no rows because there's no rows to return. You'd get NULL back if there was a row with `EntityCountCurrent` set to NULL (which can't happen anyway as that column is defined as NOT NULL).

Answer (score 4):

This is how it is supposed to work.  If you had 5 rows that were all `NULL` in the table, you would get back five `666`.